# Microsoft graph query workspaces

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, workspace

We have [Workspaces](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/book-a-workspace-in-outlook/ba-p/1524560) in our tenant and I want to query them from the Graph API.

When I query just places I get a error like in #12371. But when I query with https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/places/microsoft.graph.room it does not contain the workspace.

When I query https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/places/microsoft.graph.roomlist I can see the workspace lists. When I query https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/places/list-name@custoo.onmicrosoft.com/microsoft.graph.roomlist/rooms it is empty. Rooms do appear in the list.

How can I find all work spaces in the Graph API?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is a space `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/places/microsoft.graph.space` and `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/places/list-name@custoo.onmicrosoft.com/microsoft.graph.roomlist/spaces`

Comment: Do you know how to get workspaces in C#

Comment: It is a https call with just some headers. I suggest you look at the [graph-explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) for debugging.