# Missing type property on running https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/places

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I need to get all the conference rooms and reservable spaces in a tenant.

I believe List Places API is what I need to use (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/place-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). How do I differentiate between conference rooms and reservable spaces?

I don't see a property in the response that indicates:  '"Type": "Room" or "Space"

In my demo tenant, I created a reservable space by running PowerShell command:

> New-Mailbox xxx -Room | Set-Mailbox -Type Workspace

On running

> Get-Place xxx | fl

I see Type as 'Space'

[image]

I created a room by running PowerShell command:

> New-Mailbox yyy -Room

On running

> Get-Place yyy | fl

I see Type as 'Room'

[image]

However I don't see Type property on running

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/places/

on Graph Explorer. What am I missing?

Comment: Check this an try it in Graph Explorer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67229468/microsoft-graph-query-workspaces

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:
Alternatively, you can use microsoft graph as below
AFAIK, there will be no type in output, but if you want to get types such as rooms and spaces you can use below queries:
If you want get the spaces available you can below query:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/places/xx.onmicrosoft.com/microsoft.graph.space
```

To find rooms use below request and I followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-findrooms?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/findRooms
```

[image]

To get room list you can also use below request and I followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/place-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-1):

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/places/microsoft.graph.roomlist
```

[image]